# Основы работы с Less

Tags: css, node.js, less

Как обычно работают с LESS? На этапе создания используют их js библиотеку, которая внедряет скомпилированный код в тег style тега header, а на этапе запуска проекта любым доступным способом компилируют в CSS файл, и его подключают? 
Если нет, то как? Я не могу понять. И как связан LESS и Node.js?

Comment: Node.js связан с одним из "доступных способов".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать библиотеку js - не самый лучший ход. Незачем засорять сайт лишними скриптами. 
Если локально на компе своем верстаю, работаю так:
Есть файл style.less, он компилируется в style.css
В head в файле html подключен последний.

Как компилировать. Ну, из того, что я использовала.

1) Есть проги для винды и не только, которые могут компилировать less файлы.
Например - Crunch, Coala, WinLess, phpStorm (встроенный
компилятор. Я пробовала WinLess - довольно удобно, в интернете можно найти описание работы с этой прогой, как ее настроить на автоматическое компилирование файлов. То есть поменяли что-то в less, сохранили, css файл обновился - красота.

2) Но потом я стала пользоваться node.js и grunt, настроила компилятор с их помощью. Хотя, возможно, ради одного только less и нет смысла заниматься настройкой. По-сути с less файлами все равно происходит то же самое, что и при работе с программами. 
Это не очень сложно, если интересно, могу написать как это настроить с node.js - во всяком случае общую схему настройки и работы с ними, но гуглить все равно придется =)